# Pass string as variable to literal method type hint

Tags: javascript, typescript, literals

I would pass variable typed by string to external library method which has one of argument type hinted by defined literal. Below is the sample code problematic for me. The code has error: *Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Literal'.* How can I do to make this code works?

```
type Literal = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

function isAWithLiteral(literal:Literal): boolean
{
    return literal === 'A';
}

console.log(isAWithLiteral('B'));
console.log(isAWithLiteral('A'));

function isAWithString(literal: string): boolean
{
    return isAWithLiteral(literal);
}
```

I want to do it to completely cover the external library with my interface. I wouldn't use *Literal* dependency in any of my code expect one adapter.

Comment: What if the parameter passed to `isAWithString` isn't a `Literal`? What'd you want to happen?

Comment: I would throw Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type assertion to go from `string` to `Literal` after first checking that your string really is one of the values of `Literal`:

```
function isAWithString(literal: string): boolean
{
    if (literal !== 'A' && literal !== 'B' && literal !== 'C') {
    {
        throw new Error(`'literal' isn't a Literal: ${literal}`);
    }
    return isAWithLiteral(literal as any as Literal);
}
```

---

If `Literal` were your own code, I'd suggest using an `enum` instead so that code that needs to do this could iterate through the values. But you've said it's in an external library, so...

Comment: Something more sophisticated? I mean the external library has a lot of values in their literal. I want to do your solution but with array of literals values or iterating through literal. I'm newbie to TS and don't know well a syntax.

Comment: `Literal` is the external library code and I don't want to use it outside of my adapter.

Comment: @gargi258 - The members of a union type are not accessible as runtime values, so unfortunately, AFAIK it doesn't get more sophisticated than this. (That's one reason for using `enum` instead.) But I wouldn't have your own code passing around strings instead of `Literals`. If you don't want to use `Literal` outside your adapter (that makes sense), you can define your own `enum` with the values of `Literal` that you want to use and use that. But eventually you're going to need that `as any as Literal` assertion to cross the boundary (or a `switch` on your enum, etc.).

Comment: It's works fine for me. It's handled in only one place, adapter what I wanted achieve. Thanks!